# Execute css after transition

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

gentleman, hope you can shed me some light on this - the code below is button on a custom Card component, it should roll out on mouseover and show a text. Whats actually happening is, that on mouseover text from span instatly pops within original size of button.

Is possible to make with pure css some kind of 'callback', so ReadMoreText will get called after css for CardButton is resolved?

minimal code:

```
const CardButton = styled.button`
    &:hover {
      border-radius: 25px;
      width: 170px;
      left: calc(50% - 85px);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
`;

const ReadMoreText = styled.span`
  ${CardButton}:hover & {
    display: inline;
  }
`;

return (
  <CardButton>
    <ReadMoreText>READ MORE</ReadMoreText>
    &#129122;
  </CardButton>
)
```

Comment: The only way to Implement sequential transitions in CSS is by setting a delay in your subsequent transitions.  Otherwise, you'll have to listen for `transitionend` events in JavaScript

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I never made transition-delay work, as text is in another component. Would you mind showing me the syntax?

Comment: Actually, the `display` property that you want to change after a first transition is not a transitional property, so your CSS-only solution would have to be a keyframe animation.  Why must it be CSS only?  It would likely be more readable and easier to maintain if you add a new class after a `transitionend` event is fired.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 matter of interest. just wanna know, if there could be a css only solution, as I feel it should, but I see nothing.